# After using set_lock() should we manually subtract free_balance()?

Tags: balances, lockable-currency, locked-balance

In a custom pallet, I have been using set_lock() for a staking purpose. But once the lock is done I thought the free_balance() will reduce in the account's balance but it stays the same and only the below got updated.

```
{
  nonce: 2
  consumers: 1
  providers: 1
  sufficients: 0
  data: {
    free: 999,999,973,799,998,827,689,554 // This was same before and after set_lock as well
    reserved: 0
    miscFrozen: 250,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
    feeFrozen: 250,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two parts overlap: `available = free - lock`.

The variable `lock` is simply a number and does not represent the amount of a token. It is possible to set a lock of 100 units on an account that only has 1 unit.

Consider using the function `ensure_can_withdraw`.

---

By the way, it is recommended to switch to using `freeze` instead of `lock` after implementing this change: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12951.